# Default constructor not found for type MvxPropertyInjector

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm using MvvmCross and Xamarin Support libraries in my project and, after I updated MvvmCross from version 4.2.0 to 4.4.0 and Xamarin Support Packages from version 23.3.0 to 25.1.1, I can't execute the project. The app always crash in SplashScreen with error:  Default constructor not found for type MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxPropertyInjector. The error occurs in debug mode and release mode.

My SplashScreen:

```
[Activity(Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher",
        Theme = "@style/InflorTheme.Splash",
        NoHistory = true,
        MainLauncher = true,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class SplashScreen : MvxSplashScreenActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

               base.OnCreate(bundle);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your `LinkerPleaseInclude` file:

```
public void Include(MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxPropertyInjector injector)
{
    injector = new MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxPropertyInjector();
}
```

You might need other hints for the linker not to not throw away code that is only invoked through Reflection.

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now, happened after upgrading java and android api's. For starters there is no LinkerPleaseInclude.cs file anymore (was not added when I added mvvmcross), adding this code manually doesn't seem to do anything (This was the solution for the same problem, 2 years ago). tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581846/xamarin-linker-default-constructor-not-found-for-type-cirrious-crosscore-ioc-m/). I know the problem resides in the linking of assemblies but even if I set that to none the same issue stays.

Comment: From [changelog](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html): "Starting in Android 7.0, the system prevents apps from dynamically linking against non-NDK libraries, which may cause your app to crash. This change in behavior aims to create a consistent app experience across platform updates and different devices. Even though your code might not be linking against private libraries, it's possible that a third-party static library in your app could be doing so." Got something on this?

Comment: This is C# code that is linked away by the _mono_ linker.