# default constructor not found for type mvvmcross.platform.ioc.mvxpropertyinjector

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am new to Xamarin, and to MvvmCross (though v familiar with mvvm, and C#) and have been following the tutorial [here](https://sites.google.com/site/netdeveloperblog/xamarin/mvvmcross/learn). The app does not run on the emulator (which is not the VS one) and only crashes with this being the first exception:

default constructor not found for type mvvmcross.platform.ioc.mvxpropertyinjector.

Other posts refer to LinkerPleaseInclude.cs but the relase, linked version only crashes. The app is extremely basic and the unlinked, debug version is 54M!?! The debug version did run once, but it all seems so hit and miss. All tools used were downloaded in the last few days. Is MvvmCross a finished product, or not?
Development for Android with anything seems to go from keen anticipation to disapointment with endless googling to deal with the incessant problems and gotchas (and huge apk files...): so any help or encouragement much appreciated.

Comment: Did you add a LinkerPleaseInclude file?

Comment: I did add a class with this name, but am not sure if names are relevant here or if it is simply the component references that are relevant, and not sure what components to reference. Anyway, it made no difference. I can no longer get back to anything working. It all seems so fragile and brittle. TipCalc example: I can't get it to work on my phone and it has now stopped worling on the emulator. All seems extremely sensitive to project settings, yet these are barely documented at all. I'm on the verge of giving up with MvvmCross and even with Xamarin.

Comment: If you had added the MvvmCross StarterPack it would have added it with the relevant includes.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297713/default-constructor-not-found-for-type-mvxpropertyinjector