# Xamarin Linker: Default constructor not found for type MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxPropertyInjector

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, xamarin-linker

This is the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581846/xamarin-linker-default-constructor-not-found-for-type-cirrious-crosscore-ioc-m), but the solution is not working for me. I have a LinkerPleaseInclude.cs file with the following:

```
public void Include(MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxPropertyInjector injector)
{
    injector = new MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxPropertyInjector();
}
```

I'm using Link All as the linker behavior, but I was under the impression that including the above in LinkerPleaseInclude.cs would hint the linker to not strip it out.

Not sure if it matters, but here are some platform details:

Xamarin Studio 6.3

MvvmCross 4.4.0

.NETCore UWP 5.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file named `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` does not preserve anything by itself. It's only a convention used by Mvvmcross.

So if nothing calls into (or preserve*) your `Include` method then the linker won't mark it (as required) and the `MvxPropertyInjector` .ctor won't be marked.

`*` adding a `[Preserve]` attribute on the method will ensure the linker includes it (and everything it calls).

Comment: Adding the `[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]` attribute to your `LinkerPleaseInclude` class solves the issue for all included members in one fell swoop

Comment: That worked. Thanks. It's interesting that there were several other types/methods that required adding code for in that file, but did not apparently require [Preserve].

Comment: A `[Preserve]` is not needed if any other *used* code path reach the code you need. The linker static analyzer will make sure those are preserved.